# Prime-twins and infinite products

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product, twin-primes

For $n\geq 1$ let **the nth twin prime pair** $$(p_n,p_n+2).$$

This sequence start as $(3,5),(5,7)$, the next $(11,13)\ldots$. I have two short questions about **twin primes and infinite product defined** from these. **Can you clarify my doubts? Thanks in advance.**

> **Question.** For $a_n=\frac{1}{p_n}+\frac{1}{p_n+2}$ can be justified the convergence of $$\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-a_n)=\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{p_n^2-2}{p_n(p_n+2)}?$$

**My attempt:** Since $1>a_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ converges by **Brun's theorem** (see as quick reference this site or for example Wikipedia) then previous product is convergent to a constant *c*. *Is it a formalized proof?*

> **Question.** Is is possible to define, at least for $\Re s>1$ (the abscissa of absolute convergence) $$\tau(s)=\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-p_n^{-s})^{-1}?$$

**My attempt:** Is right say this?: Well as the (classical) **Euler product** $$\prod_{\text{p:prime}}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$$ is defined as convergent for this abscissa of convergence $\Re s>1$ and the support for previous case, the case of twin primes is a subset of the support in Euler product, then too there is convergence at least for this abscissa.

> **Example.** For example if two previous products (corresponding previous questions) can be defined, then we can write for example 
>   $$\tau(2)=c\cdot\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{p_n^3(p_n+2)}{(p_n^2-1)(p_n^2-2)},$$

where we are assuming the definition of the pair $(p_n,p_n+2)$ as before, and $c$ is the previous cited constant after first question.

Comment: Note, that it is still unknown, whether infinite many twin-primes exist. But as I understand, we assume that there are infinite many twin-primes.

Comment: @Peter At no point we need to assume this. Also note that if there are finitely many twin primes, then the product converges as it's finite.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I believe that Bruns theorem don't assume that there are infinitely many primes. To have sense (I believe that in other case we have only finite products) I belive that we should assume that there are infinitely many twin primes, but all discussion are welcome.

Comment: The infinite-product-tag indicates that the OP assumes that there infinite many. Brun's theorem is, of course, also true, if the number of twin-primes is finite. I just wanted to point out that the product in Brun's theorem could be finite.

Comment: If in the future someone want to contribute with comments to second question, if it is has mathematical sense I will appreciate this, thanks. My goal sponsor previous question was understand a few more about infinite products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following

> **Theorem**. $\prod_{n\geq1}\left(1+b_{n}\right)
>  $ converge absolutely if and only if $\sum_{n\geq1}\left|b_{n}\right|<\infty
>  $.

Then consider $b_{n}=-a_{n}
 $. So we have to check if $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left|b_{n}\right|=\sum_{n\geq1}\left|a_{n}\right|=\sum_{n\geq1}a_{n}<\infty
 $$ and this follows by the Brun's theorem, since $$\sum_{n\geq1}a_{n}=\sum_{p,p+2\in\mathfrak{P}}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right)=B\approx1.90216.
 $$

Comment: Very thanks much @MarcoCantarini